How to filter Categories and Subcategories using listview in Django
I have Category and SubCategory models in Django and I need to get descendant of Category model in 'class SubCategoriesListView'
models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Категория', max_length=150, default='name')
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('SubCategory', max_length=150, default=True)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField('Pic', upload_to='img', null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

How to filter subcategories linked with category model? (I have to use detailview later, so solution must be with the using ListView model)
views.py
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'catalog/category_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'

class SubCategoriesListView(Category, ListView):
    model = SubCategory
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
    template_name = 'catalog/subcategory_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'subcategory_list'


I don't really get why it needs to be a ListView because you will use a DetailView later?

the idea is to render all categories on 'catalog/category_list.html', choose one and render all subcategories on 'catalog/subcategory_list.html', and finally pick one item from the list and open some info about it on 'catalog/detail.html', for this I use DetailView. I just started to learn Django and don't know more convenient way  to do it.

But you can use any template for any view. These are just views defined for common scenario's to reduce the amount of boilerplate logic.

You can filter on the primary key of an item:
#                   no Category 🖟
class SubCategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = SubCategory
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
    template_name = 'catalog/subcategory_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'subcategory_list'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(category_id=self.kwargs['category_id'])
        )
in the urls.py we register this as:
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'category/<int:category_id>/',
        SubCategoriesListView.as_view(),
        name='subcategories',
    )
]
You can then visit category/14 for example to get a list of all SubCategorys belonging to the Category with pk=14.

as I know ListView won’t have an id on the self.kwargs and error File "/catalog/views.py", line 77, in get_queryset
.filter(category_id=kwargs['category_id'])
KeyError: 'category_id'  prove that

@evgenyiypasukov: sorry, I made a typo, it is self.kwargs.
